# Dashboard Designer: Permissions issue

Tags: dashboard-designer-2013

I recently created a cube. Set it up with full permission and read permissions.
In the roles section.

In the dashboard designer I can ad the cube in the Data Connections area.

But when create an alalytic grid. I get the error.

```
Error running data source query. 

Contact the administrator for more details.

You do not have permission to see this data. 

Error running data source query.

The  cube either does not exist or has not been processed.

Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.AdomdErrorResponseException: The  cube either does not exist or has not been processed.
 at            Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.AdomdConnection.XmlaClientProvider.Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.IExecuteProvider.ExecuteMultidimensional(ICommandContentProvider contentProvider, AdomdPropertyCollection commandProperties, IDataParameterCollection parameters)
 at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.AdomdCommand.ExecuteCellSet()
     at     Microsoft.PerformancePoint.Scorecards.DataSourceProviders.AdomdDataSourceProvider.RunQueryInternal(String query, Boolean isCellSet, Int32 sessionTimeout)

PerformancePoint Services error code 10116.
```

I've set the unattended account in sharepoint. And all the other reports work just fine in the dashboard designer. It's just the cube data that is giving me the issue. There's a permission somewhere that I can't find.

Here's another error that comes with that one.

```
An exception occurred while running a report.  The following details may     help you to diagnose the problem:
Error Message: Error running data source query.
    <br>
    <br>
    Contact the administrator for more details.
Dashboard Name: 
Dashboard Item name: 
Report Location: {017645e8-f451-b291-aca9-bc64b00e7fd7}
Request Duration: 77.91 ms
User: xxx\xxx
Parameters: 

Exception Message: Error running data source query.
Inner Exception Message: 
Stack Trace:    at        Microsoft.PerformancePoint.Scorecards.Server.PmServer.ExecuteAnalyticReportWithParameters(RepositoryLocation analyticReportViewLocation, BIDataContainer biDataContainer)
   at Microsoft.PerformancePoint.Analytics.ServerRendering.OLAPBase.OlapViewBaseControl.ExtractReportViewData()
   at Microsoft.PerformancePoint.Analytics.ServerRendering.OLAPBase.OlapViewBaseControl.CreateRenderedView(StringBuilder sd)
   at Microsoft.PerformancePoint.Scorecards.ServerRendering.NavigableControl.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer)


PerformancePoint Services error code 20604.
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to reconfigure the key in **Secure Store Service**

Select **Refresh Key** and entered the pass phrase to **regenerate the key**

**OR**

You need to give the permission to your account in SQL server using below steps.

1. Right-click on the **SQL Server Management Studio** icon and then select "**Run as Administrator**"
2. Select "**Analysis Services**" from the "**Server type**:" drop-down list in the "**Connect to Server**" dialog box, then click connect.
3. Right-click on the localhost definition in the Object Explorer panel and select **Properties**.
4. Click on **Security** in the left panel of the Analysis Server **Properties**.
5. Click the **Add...** button and type your user name and click the **Check Names** button to make sure you typed it right. Then click **OK**.
6. Click OK.

Comment: I went in and regenerated the key but no dice. And my service account and my account are both in there when I check the management studio. Do I need to restart the server or IIS in order for the key to take hold? I have a feeling there's some obscure setting we are missing.

Comment: You need to restart the server & services both

Comment: Let me try that.

Comment: no dice. Still do not have permission

Comment: I added a second error that comes along with the other one.

Comment: Still not working.

Comment: You need to increase the time out from IIS for this web application.

Comment: Do you mean in the web.config? Which key exactly?

Comment: In the IIS for specific web application.

Comment: I change the httpRuntime and added executionTimeout="300" . <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="51200" requestValidationMode="2.0" executionTimeout="300" /> . Still the same issue.

Comment: I ended up re installing sharepoint. Solved the problem.

Comment: Given solution is also one of the workaround to solve such problems. Give some justice to my answer if possible.